# How to access all objects in an array of objects with jQuery data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, yaml, freemarker

I am trying to use jQuery's **data()** selector (in a Freemarker template) to pass yaml data to JS.
So while I am able to pass "shallow" key/value pairs, passing an array/sequence of objects/hasmaps doesn't really do the job and I get a string, which can't be used or converted to a regular array of objects:

**Freemarker**

```
<#local xAxis=20 />
<#local data=content.data /> // A yaml sequence containing two hashmaps
<#local config='{"xAxis": ${xAxis}, "data": "${data}"}' /> //quotations for parsing to stop config becoming a string
   <div id="" data-js-config='${config}'>
```

**JS**

```
const config = $("[data-js-config]").data("js-config")
console.log(config)
```

The result is that the data array becomes a string which I can't use:
`{xAxis: 20, data: "[{key1=value1},{key2=value2}]"}`

I would like the data string to be converted into a regular array with objects with key/value pairs, just as xAxis was converted to a key/value pair.

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Don't put `${data}` in double-quotes.

Comment: However, after that you're going to have the problem that your YAML array notation, as posted, may not be valid JSON.

Answer (score 1):

content.data cannot be

```
[{key1=value1},{key2=value2}]
```

but needs to be

```
[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]
```

then it will work

```js
const config = $("[data-js-config]").data("js-config")
console.log(config)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="" 
data-js-config='{"xAxis": 20, "data": [{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]'></div>
```

If not, do YOU need the double quotes around ${data} and you will need to parse the config.data string

Comment: I also think that the double-quotes around `${data}` in the `<#local>` tag are probably wrong.

Comment: @Pointy unless data is NOT valid JSON, then they need to parse config.data string using regex or similar

Comment: well yes of course, but the original problem is that the whole array was added to the JSON as a *string*, not a JSON array.

Comment: Thank you, but that is exactly the issue - `${data}` has to have quotes to allow `config` to even be parsed. Otherwise, `config` becomes a string.  The original `content.data comes` from yaml and not a json:
`data:
    - key: "value"
    - key2: 'value2'
`

Comment: That is the reason it returns `[{key1=value1},{key2=value2}]` instead of `[{"key1":"value1"},{"key2":"value2"}]`